# Which ANABIN Certificate do I need for Work Visa? If I want Aufenthaltserlaubnis (Resident permit) Germany

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany

I am a professional software developer with an experience of 5 years. I am currently in Karachi, Pakistan. I got an offer from Munich Germany company.

To get the Visa from the German General Consulate (Karachi), they are asking for the **Education Equivalency of my education from ANABIN**. I have completed high school (12th standard) and my bachelor's degree is in progress, I have completed 2 years of my bachelor's degree and 2 years are remaining. I also got clearance from ZAV (Bundesagentur für arbeit) and I am allowed to work in Germany.

Would you be so kind to suggest which equivalency certificate should I apply?

Comment: You should presumably apply for a certificate for the highest degree you hold. From the sound of it, you only have a high school degree though and it might be difficult to get a visa with that. Years of experience or course credits do not necessarily compensate for the lack of a proper degree, especially in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

The [Anabin](http://anabin.kmk.org/anabin.html) certification you have been requested evaluates foreign education to classify it within the German education system. The database search higher education, university, and from another country’s state or state-recognized institutions.

Completion of high school would not be assessed; if an associate degree was issued upon completion of two years of university, that might be.

It would be best to contact Zentralstelle für ausländisches Bildungswesen (ZAB) directly:

[Central Office for Foreign Education (ZAB) in the Secretariat of the Conference of Ministers of Education and Cultural Affairs](https://www.kmk.org/service/anerkennung-auslaendischer-abschluesse/zeugnisbewertung-fuer-auslaendische-hochschulqualifikationen.html) 
Graurheindorfer Straße 157 
53117 Bonn 
(Postfach 2240, 53012 Bonn)
E-mail: Zabservice@kmk.org
Phone: 0228 501-664
Mon, Tue, Thu: 10-12 hrs / 14-15 hrs 
Fri: 10-12 hrs